# iOS: how to access a system notification created from a NFC tag with a deeplink (and eventually erase it)?

Tags: ios, notifications, nfc

We have setup some NFC tags which contain a deeplink opening our app.

I would like to know if it is either possible for the notifications created when reading the tag to erase the previous ones, or to do it from the app once one of these system notifications is tapped.

I tried looking into `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications()`, but the array doesn't contain any, so I guess iOS handles them differently.

Thank you for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do in your app because these aren't notifications *from your app*.

I am not sure why this would generally be an issue because I would expect that after scanning the NFC tag, the user would typically tap the notification to open your app, which will remove it.

You will only be left with multiple notifications, as you show in your screenshot, if the user is scanning NFC tags and then ignoring the prompt to open your app.